# What is the best way to check if a value mapped to an address is smaller than something?

Tags: solidity, mapping

I have a simple mapping of an address mapped to a value. I need to be able to see if any value associated with an address is smaller than a given value. What would be the best way of doing this. I would rather not have to keep track of all addresses and loop through that.

Comment: Do you also want to know which address is smaller? How many inserts/ removals into that mapping do you expect?

Comment: I want to perform an action on the addresses that have a value smaller than the threshold like call another function.